# Value Error in Keras in model.fit

Tags: keras

Im trying to build neural network and doing this stuff below:

```py
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation

model.add(Dense(units=64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=10))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='sgd',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Than I assign x_train and y_train as numpy arrays:

```py
x_train=np.asarray(X_train)
y_train=np.asarray(y_train)
x_train.shape #(261, 8)
y_train.shape #(261,)

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=32)
```

On output I have an error :

```py
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (None, 100) but got array with shape (261, 8)
```

What I did wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't you first define your model as `Sequential()`?

Comment: Also, you didn't define a `input_shape` for your first `Dense` layer. Without extra info I'm not sure if I can help you.

Comment: I need to make classification and I have x_train and y_train for that.So in sckit-learn all works fine but in keras I have problems with dimensions

Comment: One of the reasons might be the use of `categorical_crossentropy`. Are your input matrices binary?

Comment: first I did label encoder for x_train`for x in cross1.columns:
    f = LabelEncoder()` y_train just a 3 class vector

Comment: you also need to specify an `input_shape()` in the first dense layer

Comment: Can you add a small sample of your x and y data? Just the first 5 samples of each should be sufficient. You can't use categorical_crossentropy with a y of shape (261,) and an output of dense(10)

Comment: problem solved by converting x_train and y_train to numpy array